# Spring @TestConfiguration affecting other test classes

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-test

I have several integration test classes, they all import configuration from a single `@Configuration` class, which is creating an `externalApi` mocked bean in a particular way (for illustration purposes, passing `true` as a constructor argument):

```
@Configuration
public class TestConfig {
  
  @Bean
  @Primary
  ExternalApi externalApi() {
    return new MockExternalApi(true); // <-- true by default for all test classes
  }
}
```

But for a particular integration test class, I need to create that bean differently (let's say passing `false` as a constructor argument). In order to do that, I tried using `@TestConfiguration` in a static inner class as follows:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest("spring.main.allow-bean-definition-overriding=true")
@Import(TestConfig.class)
@ActiveProfiles("test")
public class ExampleIT {

  @TestConfiguration
  public static class ExternalApiConfig {

    @Bean
    @Primary
    ExternalApi externalApi() {
      return new MockExternalApi(false); // <-- false for this particular test class
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void someTest() {...}
}
```

That works, however, when executing all my integration test classes at once (with `maven verify`, for example), all test classes executing after this one break. Since they share the same context, it seems that, after changing that bean, it remains changed (i.e., with that `false` argument) for all subsequent test classes as well. I tried to fix that using `@DirtiesContext` at the class level, so the context could be reloaded for next test classes, but it didn't work.

Is there a way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

**Note**: If I add that same `@TestConfiguration` static inner class to all my other integration test classes, doing the opposite, i.e., creating the `externalApi` bean back with `true` arg, then they all work. But I certainly don't wish having to do that.

Comment: What about removing `@Import(TestConfig.class)` for this particular test? Or are there multiple bean definitions in there? Also, can you try to name the `externalApi` differently for this integration test, maybe `innerExternalApi`. Somehow the Spring Context caching mechanism must identify that you're working with a different context here.

Answer (score 11):

This works:

Configuration class:

```
// @TestConfiguration
// Put this class in a separate file
// NB! Do not annotate this class with @TestConfiguration,
// or else the configuration will be propagated to other tests!
public class UkvServiceTestContextConfiguration {
```

Test suite that uses this configuration:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)

// NB! Do not use a nested static configuration class, use an external configuration class.
// Nested static configuration class gets propagated to other tests!
@Import(UkvServiceTestContextConfiguration.class)
```

public class UkvServiceTest {

Comment: Thanks a lot. Importing test configuration (instead of annotating it with @TestConfiguration) fixed the problem. Now I can use separate test configurations for different tests without those configurations affecting other tests.

Comment: Thanks. the first part of your solution worked for me. Removing the `@TestConfiguration` and adding the `@Import`. However, I added the configuration class as a static class and it worked, so I believe you should review your answer.

Answer (score 2):

This *seems* like a bug in the Spring runner; `@TestConfiguration` shouldn't be propagated. As a workaround, try adding `@DirtiesContext` to your test to force a refresh.